# powershell doesn't execute commands from PATH

Tags: powershell

Running commands from PATH doesn't seem to work for me. I enter a command, I press enter, and then the powershell resets and even minimizes. And nothing happens.

I used set-policy to Unrestricted, still doesn't work. But it seems that I CAN run internal commands.

I also cannot launch CMD. When I start it, it flashes for a second before closing again.

Album:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BX9cA.jpg

Get-ExecutionPolicy

```
Unrestricted
```

$PSVersionTable

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.18362.752
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.18362.752
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Get-Host

```
Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 5.1.18362.752
InstanceId       : 145d6dd6-dcd3-4be6-836f-6080ee0b1b18
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : en-US
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy
DebuggerEnabled  : True
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace
```

Comment: What does it mean that commands from PATH don't run? Which commands, do you try to run?

Comment: What do you get if you run `Get-Command [executable name]`?

Comment: @MikkeIT just try to launch visual code.

Comment: I cannot repro what you are seeing here. This is not an ExecutionPolicy issue, since the EP is about controlling scripts, and you are starting an executable. You are just starting VScode from the PSCore, firstly, why? Just start VScode from the shortcut or WinKey and code. Set VScode to default PSCore, if that is waht you want to use as teh terminal.

Comment: @Alex_P Any command from the PATH list. None of them are working.

@MathiasR.Jessen That works. I get 
```

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     code.cmd                                           0.0.0.0    C:\Users\Mikkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd
```

@postanote
 @JPBlanc 
I can launch VS Code from my app menu, sure, but it was example. I also need to access CLI only tools. And they dont work either.